# WooCommerce Variation Try or Buy with ACF

Tags: woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I have a strange request that I don't know how to approach or get working with WooCommerce.

On the product page we have two options. Buy or Try this product.

So generally "Buy" for say, $49.95 would include shipping and you can checkout as normal.

But "Try" for say $6.95 - that $6.95 is your shipping charge to try it, and the full product price at the end of the 15-30 days is the $49.95.

When you select Try you need to agree to some terms and conditions before you can add it to the cart.

So I think Advanced Custom Fields to add a conditional WYSIWYG to add in some specific information and make the Checkbox required to add to cart. I'm not required to think about the billing side of things just to get this Try or Buy working on a product page.

How the heck do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward with ACF.

Create a field like you mentioned as a wysiwig editor for the content.

Create a checkbox field and set Required: to yes. Add conditioning to hide it unless the checkbox from clicking the trial button is populated.

Create a checkbox field, that you will use to create the Trial button. Restyle it to be a button.

Now on the try button, add some JS in order to make a popup appear.

They read the popup and check the box.

Do an if statement to check if the checkbox has accept or whatever you set the checked yes value to. If it is equal to that value, add a styling or class to the try button to make it disappear. Remove styling or a class off an extra button that allows you to then get the product buy pressing it.

This seems like it would work, you'd then just need to figure out how to get the product charge to differ. Perhaps when they click that button it populates a hidden coupon field which applies a discount to the basket making it the amount you want the cost to be? Or it changes the value they have to pay. I will let you figure that one out.